# Get method of frisby does not work with https

Tags: javascript, frisby.js

I am new to frisby test. today i found I can't access https://ip address from friby api

for example:

```
frisby.create('my test').get("https://199.59.148.20")
output: connect error

frisby.create('my test').get("https://api.twitter.com")
this one works
```

please advise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is beacuse the unsafe connection (non-trusted SSL certificate). If you open same URL in a browser, it will ask for confirmation before to continue with the insecure connection.

To do the same thing in `frisby`, add a second param to `.get(...)` method to specify `strictSSL = false` as follows:

```
var frisby = require('frisby');

frisby.create('Get a https resource')
      .get('https://199.59.148.20', { strictSSL: false })
      .expectStatus(200) // For this case/IP-address this fails as it returns a 404
      .inspectBody()
      .toss();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to non-trusted SSL certificate. you can include this line at the beginning of your firsby test:

`process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"`

This will direct non-rejection of SSL cert.