# Frisby.js Error: tunneling socket could not be established

Tags: rest, proxy, frisby.js

I am trying to test an REST API on my local machine using frisby.js .  It throws the following error.

Error: tunneling socket could not be established.

The machine address is something like 'https://machine_name:8443'

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are behind a `proxy`. Then, to make your frisby test working, you need to apply `proxy configuration` as follows:

```js
var frisby = require('frisby');

frisby.globalSetup({
    request: {
        proxy: 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy' // Provide proxy info (host, port) here
    }
});

frisby.create('Your spec description here')
    .get('https://machine_name:8443')
    .expectStatus(200)
    .toss();
```

Note also that you are using `HTTPS` protocol. Then you may find useful my answer in **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219794/get-method-of-frisby-does-not-work-with-https)** in case you have problems with `SSL` certificates